# Did I find the inverse function right?

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

This is the function: $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ defined by 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
         \dfrac{1}{1 - 2x}, & \text{$x < 0$}\\[2mm]
         1 + 2x, & \text{$x \geq 0$}
         \end{cases}
$$

[This is the inverse function:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJGHV.jpg) $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
         \dfrac{x - 1}{2x}, & \text{$x \in (0, 1)$}\\[2 mm]  
         \dfrac{x - 1}{2}, & \text{$x \in (1, \infty)$}
         \end{cases}
$$

I proved that f is injective and surjective so f is bijective thus there is an inverse function, I just need to be sure I determined the inverse correctly.

Comment: Well, just plug it in. See if $f\circ g=g\circ f=\text{identity}$.

Comment: Inverse is not defined for $x=1$. Easy fix

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting a link to an image since links may get broken.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.